# Integrating login Authentication module with existing Angular JS application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, authentication, routes

I have purchases an Angular JS theme and started developing our application. The `$routeProvider` of that app looks like this:

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/dashboard'
    })
    .when('/:page', {
        templateUrl: function($routeParams) {
            return 'views/'+ $routeParams.page +'.html';
        },
        controller: 'PageViewController'
    })
    .when('/:page/:child*', {
        templateUrl: function($routeParams) {
            return 'views/'+ $routeParams.page + '/' + $routeParams.child + '.html';
        },
        controller: 'PageViewController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/dashboard'
    });
```

It is a single page Application

Now I need to integrate login authentication module to it. I'm relatively new to AngularJS. I searched and got lot of articles about login, authentication modules for AngularJS application (few good answers in `stack overflow` as well) , which I could understand how it works.

But I'm not knowing how to make login work together with the existing application. Either having by having 2 different apps (one for login-authentication, and one for main app) or integrating login as separate `angular.module` in the main app. Please guide me how should I do...

All the examples have only 2 or 3 items in the `$routeProvider` including `login` and `logout` and the main app page. But in this case, main app page itself has many route providers.

I think I have some basic disconnect here. Please help me understanding the disconnect and integrating login-authentication with the existing application.

I don't know what more code components to add. Will share additional code if required.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it could be a long answer if you are searching for a complete solution. What I could say quickly is that, in my opinion, you have to:

1. create a login page and put it in views folder
2. create a specific login Controller
3. add a route to login page before ':/page' route that uses the login Controller you just created
4. if your application require authentication, you have to edit PageViewController in order to redirect to login page if the current user is not logged yet.

As I said, it's a quick answer in order to the big work you have to do, but I hope you found this useful.

Bye

Comment: Thank you crisp answer. Please let me know in the same way, what should I do in `pageViewController`. As of now its empty.

Comment: First of all, you have to check if there is a main controller (putted in the body tag, the attribute is ng-controller). If yes then you should put there a variable on the scope (i.e. $scope.user that you will use to put user data.

In the PageViewController create a function to check if the user is correctly logged (that means that $scope.user is not null) and call it at the end of controller declaration. This function should redirect to login page if the user is null.